# Load Azure Blob CSV in SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis

I am trying to load a Blob CSV into SSIS in a Flat File destination.

[image]

You can see in my source editor that columns are appearing (So its reading my CSV blob file)

[image]

When I run SSIS, it returns me these errors:

```
[Azure Blob Source] Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Warning: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Unlikely the issue, but I was curious - if you double click the line between the source and destination, on the metadata/properties section, what data types does it specify for Flag, ISSUES ID, etc? Do you have some weird RBAC permission where you can read the header but not the actual data? In the azure blob source editor, is there a Preview button that shows existing data? Are you running the entire package or just the task?

Comment: Hi   billinkc, when i am looking on the metadata all my field are displayed Field Name and data type. Correct i can read the header but not the actual data. Is it some security settings on Azure side?